# Determining whether sets of vectors form a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is $\{(1,1,0,0),(0,0,1,1)\}$ a basis for the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ consisting of all vectors of the form $(a,a+b,b,b)$ with $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$?

Here is how I proceeded:
First note that

$$(a,a+b,b,b)=a(1,1,0,0)+b(0,1,1,1).$$

And so:  $$\{(a,a+b,b,b):a,b\in \mathbb{R}\}=span_{\mathbb{R}}(\{(1,1,0,0),(0,1,1,1)\}).$$

Now, I put $(1,1,0,0),(0,1,1,1)$ to find what exactly these two vectors span.

But, then, I am stuck, what do I do?

Is there any other method to do this?

Comment: Did you mean to start with $\{(1,1,0,0),(0,0,1,1)\}$ or did you mean $\{(1,1,0,0),(0,1,1,1)\}$?

Comment: I triple checked what I wrote and what I wrote is right Curtis!

Comment: Then if the solution manual said it is a basis it must have just made a typo and most likely meant to write down the second pair of vectors !

Comment: Exactly what I thought.

Comment: Then your suspicion is correct, and Peter has pointed out a nice counterexample (as you have already seen), good work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two vectors do not span the given subspace, and therefore cannot form a basis. Consider the vector
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1+1\\
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}$$
which is in your subspace ($a=b=1$). This is not spanned by the two vectors, because any linear combination of them:

$$c_1\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
+
c_2\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
c_1 \\
c_1 \\
c_2 \\
c_2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

would have to have the same first and second coordinate.

Comment: Perfect. My solutions manual said it was a basis. I knew there was something wrong!

Answer (score 1):

To add to Peter's solution, 
If instead you were given $\mathcal{B}=\{(1,1,0,0),(0,1,1,1)\}$, then you have already shown that $(1,1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,1,1)$ span the subspace consisting of vectors of the form $(a,a+b,b,b)$. Call this vector subspace $V$. To show that $\mathcal{B}=\{(1,1,0,0),(0,1,1,1)\}$ is a basis it remains to show that $(1,1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,1,1)$ are linearly independent (by definition of a basis).

Suppose that for some $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{R}$ we have 
$$\alpha  (1,1,0,0)+\beta (0,1,1,1)=0$$

Equating things component wise, the first and fourth component gives us that $\alpha=0,\beta=0$, so the vectors are linearly independent and thus $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $V$.

Comment: Great comment.!